# Pass an array of integers to ElasticSeach template

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch, mustache

I am trying to pass an array of integers to ElasticSearch template using the below mustache template.

```
{{#filter5_terms}} 
"terms": {
"{{filter5_name}}": [
"{{#filter5_lt}}", 
"{{.}}",                                
"{{/filter5_lt}}"  ]
}
{{/filter5_terms}}
```

Above works, If I pass a string array (Ex: ["A","B"]. But the same is failing with the int array [1,2] with Nested: NumberFormatException[For input string: ""];  error.

Reference: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-template.html#_passing_an_array_of_strings

Can you please let me know if I am missing anything?

Thanks
Anil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did fix this.
We can use the below to replace the integer array into ElasticSearch query.

```
"terms": {
"{{filter5_name}}": {{filter5_lt}}
}
```

ElasticSearch documentation has an example to replace string arrays and I tried to use the same for integer arrays and it did not work.

So I had to use the above which is provided in Mustache templating examples.

Thanks
Anil

Comment: Hi Anil, Can I know the full syntax please ? I am trying the below , but not working . Can I know what I am doing wrong here ?  POST _scripts/Select-Users-ByIDs
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "mustache",
    "source": {
      "query": {
        "terms": {
         "{{filter5_name}}": "{{filter5_lt}}"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

GET cs_user/cs_user/_search/template
{
  "id": "Select-Users-ByIDs",
  "params": {
    "filter5_lt":[1,2],
    "filter5_name":"_id"
  }
  
}

Comment: In your solution the json is essentially malformed... 

To make it a valid ES query you have to wrap `{{filter5_lt}}` with quotes, then we are back to the very beginning.... : (

```
{
  "terms" : {
    "{{filter5_name}}" : "{{filter5_lt}}"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You really shouldn't rely on that, as the format is an inner implementation of Mustache and thus, subject to change. For example, if you try to emulate that using [mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/), you'll get something like:

```
"terms: {
  "property": 3,4
}
```

To workaround this problem, you should *add square brackets* to the templated values. So, your example becomes:

```
"terms": {
  "{{filter5_name}}": [{{filter5_lt}}]
}
```

And that will get you what you want.

At least, this is true in mustache.js 2.2.1