# How to pass array to ElasticSearch search template using mustache?

Tags: elasticsearch

This is a part of my search query template:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "platform_id": [
              "{{#platform_ids}}",
              "{{.}}",
              "{{/platform_ids}}"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
```

This solution was taken from the elasticsearch official website.

I have this query:

```
GET _render/template
{
  "id": "fddf", 
  "params": {
    "query_string": "tinders",
    "platform_ids": [1, 2]
  }
}
```

And this results with this:

```
"terms" : {
  "platform_id" : [
    "",
    "1",
    "",
    "2",
    ""
  ]
}
```

But I need this:

```
"terms" : {
  "platform_id" : [
    1, 2
  ]
}
```

Couldn't find a solution for this.

Comment: What language are you using to render the mustache templates? If you are using something like python/javascript, there are probably easier ways of accomplishing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your template as shown below

```
GET _render/template
{
  "source": "{\"query\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"terms\":{\"platform_id\":[{{#platform_id}}{{value}}{{#comma}},{{/comma}}{{/platform_id}}]}}]}}}",
  "params": {
    "platform_id": [
      {
        "value": 1,
        "comma": true
      },
      {
        "value": 2
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Result would be

```
    {
  "template_output": {
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "terms": {
              "platform_id": [
                1,
                2
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Refer to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31316561/elasticsearch-indexed-search-template-generates-empty-strings-in-array) to get a detailed explanation**

Comment: Thank you, that worked after I realized that I have to pass source template as string completely. I was trying all these methods with source being a json, not a string that contains json and mustache templates.

Answer (score 2):

**Request:**

```
GET _render/template
{
  "source": "{ \"query\": { \"terms\": {{#toJson}}bids{{/toJson}} }}",
  "params": {
    "bids":[1,2]
  }
}
```

**Response:**

```
{
  "template_output" : {
    "query" : {
      "terms" : [
        1,
        2
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Try below:**

```
"query": {
"bool": {
  "must": [
    {
      "terms": {
        "platform_id": {{#toJson}}platform_id{{/toJson}}
      }
    }
  ],
```

Comment: All the problem was in fact that I pass source template as json, not a string containing json. This method also works, thank you!