# Passing a dynamic list of doubles as param value in ElasticSearch templates

Tags: elasticsearch, mustache

I am trying to pass an array of doubles to an ElasticSearch template using the below mustache template

```
PUT _scripts/my_template
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "mustache",
    "source": {
      "query": {
        "script_score": {
          "query": {
            "match_all": {}
          },
          "script": {
            "source": "knn_score",
            "lang": "knn",
            "params": {
              "field": "{{field}}",
              "query_value": "{{query_value}}",
              "space_type": "{{space_type}}"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I render the template by passing the param values

```
GET _render/template
{
  "id": "my_template",
  "params": {
    "field": "embeddings_field",
    "query_value": [0.1, 0.2],
    "space_type": "cosinesimil"
  }
}
```

I get an error about casting String as an ArrayList which I understand.

I have looked in related SO posts but having no luck. This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31316561/elasticsearch-indexed-search-template-generates-empty-strings-in-array/31317720#31317720) looked promising but I have been only able to get it show as a list of strings rather than list of doubles. The size of the list can itself vary so that is one more downside with the solution.

Is it possible to parameterize this value in the mustache template?

{EDIT}
Based on @Val's suggestion I was able to get the rendering working. However when I run the rendered template against the index it gives me an error

```
GET my_index/_search/template
{
  "id": "my_template",
  "params": {
    "field": "embeddings",
    "query_value": [
            -0.03159378841519356,
            0.0715613141655922
          ],
        "space_type": "cosinesimil"
  }
}
```

The error I get is

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Required [script]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Required [script]"},"status":400}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it [this way](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-template.html#search-template-convert-json) (+ store the query as a string instead of JSON):

```
PUT _scripts/my_template
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "mustache",
    "source": """
     {
      "query": {
        "script_score": {
          "query": {
            "match_all": {}
          },
          "script": {
            "source": "knn_score",
            "lang": "knn",
            "params": {
              "field": "{{field}}",
              "query_value": {{#toJSON}}query_value{{/toJSON}},
              "space_type": "{{space_type}}"
            }
          }
        }
      }
     }
    """
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks @val, I was able to render it correctly using above. However I get an error when trying to run the template against the index. It complains about requiring a value for "script" but I have a feeling it might be getting confused because I already have a `script` in my template

Comment: Can you update your question and show how you execute the template query and the error you get?

Comment: I have added how I am executing the search and the exact error I am getting

Comment: thanks so much for helping out! I did figure it out. The exact knn search had an extra brace. Its working now

Comment: Ok, glad you figured it out!